# What is the use of max m in the lazy quantifiers {n,m}??

Tags: regex, quantifiers, reluctant-quantifiers

In regex, we have [greedy and lazy quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html). The greedy quantifier `{n,m}` matches the preceding atom/character/group a minimum of n and a maximum of m occurrences, inclusive.

If I have a collection of strings:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

With `a{2,4}`, it matches:

- nothing on first line
- aa on second
- aaa on third
- aaaa on fourth
- (aaaa), (aaaa), and (aa) on fifth line

That makes sense.

However, if I have a lazy quantifier `a{2,4}?` I get:

- nothing on first line
- aa on second line
- aa on third line
- (aa) and (aa) on fourth line
- (aa), (aa), (aa), (aa), and (aa) on fifth line

That actually makes sense. It finds the least amount of possible match.

The part that I want to clarify - is there any usefulness to pass any lazy quantifier in the form of `{n,m}?` a max value `m` (in this case, the 4 in `{2,4}?`)? Isn't the result is *always* the same as `{2,}?`?

Is there a scenario where passing a max (like the 4 in `{2,4}?`) is useful in lazy quantifier?

*Disclaimer: I am actually using the regular expression to search inside Vim (`/a{-2,4}`), not in any scripting language. I think the principle of the question is still the same.*

Comment: It depends on the regex library/implementation. What is the regex flavor/programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matters when you need to consider what *follows* the lazily quantified expression. Laziness is used to prevent characters from being consumed by a later expression in a concatenation. Consider the string `aaaaab`:

1. The string is not matched by `a{2,4}?b`, as there are too many `a`s for `a{2,4}` to match.
2. The string is matched by `a{2,}?b`, since it can match as many `a`s as necessary.

Comment: In case of aaaaab, a{2,4}b would match aaaab, right? However, I was expecting a{2,4}?b to match aab but when I tried it instead it matches aaaab. Interesting.

Comment: I think the issue is that lazy or not, it's still going to start as far left as possible. Consider something like `re.match(r'a*(a{2,4}?b)', 'aaaa')`.